# Setting up Raid 1 in a dell poweredge R300 server

Tags: raid1

Hello everybody i have a dell poweredge r300 server, and i want to set up Raid 1, how can i do that? thnx.

PS: i cant access to the utility mode.

Comment: We'll need a lot more detail. Do you want to do software RAID or hardware RAID? If software, what OS are you running? If hardware, what RAID card does the server have? What do you mean by "i cant access to the utility mode"?

Answer (score 1):

Well,

Maybe this info can point you in the rigth direction, :

[RAID Configuration and Management](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/storage/raid/perc5/en/ug/html/chapterh.htm#wp1069357) 
*Dell™ PowerEdge™ Expandable RAID Controller 5/i and 5/E User's Guide*

What you are looking for is to set up a virtual disk:
[Setting up Virtual Disk](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/storage/raid/perc5/en/ug/html/chapterh.htm#wp1069357)

Hope this can help you

Comment: +1. Funny how we need to tell people here to read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Hit CTRL+C Keys during the post and it takes you to SAS configuration utility. And then selected Adapter:SAS6IR and hit enter, then gave options for RAID properties where you then selected RAID 1/0. Hit C to create.